# Measure of the angle between 2 tangent circumferences

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

$2$ circumferences are external tangent in $Q$, $PA$ and $PB$ are tangents in $A$ and $B$ respectively, and the straight line $t$ is tangent to both circumferences in $Q$. If $\angle APB=80º$, then $\angle AQB=?$

I made a drawing:

[image]

Any hints?

Comment: Sorry, edited, i figured that's wrong.

Comment: I think $140^\circ$ is right. Why don't you show your work that led to that answer, so we can confirm it or find the mistake if there is one?

Comment: Ok, i'm going to add it.

Comment: Hint: $\Delta PAQ$ and $\Delta PQB$ are isosceles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explain this:
$$\measuredangle AQB=\frac{1}{2}(360^{\circ}-80^{\circ})=140^{\circ}.$$